# SFTP Connection without the use of 3rd party apps

Tags: ftp, sftp

Is there any way to connect to an SFTP using either Windows 7 or Windows Server 2012 without the need of a 3rd party app?

Comment: All the other mature systems comes with something similar built-in, except the Windows ...

Answer (score 2):

No version of windows comes with its own SFTP client. Due to a lack of a builtin public key authentication mechanism, windows will have to rely on other applications handling this.